# Java package net.proxy.core

Tags: java, proxy

Hey guys I really cant find this package can you help me.

```
import net.proxy.core.Connection;
import net.proxy.core.Proxy;
import net.proxy.core.exception.ProxyClosedException;
import net.proxy.core.exception.ProxyConnexionException;
```

Comment: Which, out of these 4 packages can’t you find?

Comment: How are we supposed to do that? Were is this from?

Comment: I can guess that it’s certainly not ProxyConnexion

Comment: are you sure they are from external sources?

Comment: Why would someone upvote this?!

Comment: non of them cant be found ... the source is for a Agent call GET that is from here: http://www.fitnesslab.altervista.org/index.php/en/download/source-code/86-source-code